# Silent Installation of exe and Launch the Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, cmd

I am going to install the my project silently using the following options from the C#.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = tempPath + "myproject.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "/s /v/qn";
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    exitcode = exeProcess.ExitCode;
}
```

It installs my projects sucessfully.but I need to Launch the installed application after the installation. How I can Do this? Is there any Additional arguments I need to pass to Launch the product after the installation?

Thanks in Advance,
Roshil

Comment: Assuming that "myproject.exe" is an installer, just make the installer do the launch when its finished.

Comment: If it's an installer ==> perform this taskl in the installer. If not ==> start a new process with the installed program.

Comment: ok Thanks for your Reply..Is there any any arguments to Launch the installer?

Comment: I am using Visual studio limitted edition to create the installer and set the "Do you want to give the users the option to launch your application when the installation completes" checkbox while created the  installer. But silent installation does not seem to Launch..

Comment: Is there some reason that the installer needs to launch the installed application?  Can't your code launch it, once it sees that the installer has exited?